# Restore to a previous backup point with Windows 7 backup

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, restore, versioning

I wonder if it is possible to restore previous versions of files or system states with Windows 7 backup.

Let's assume a backup has been set with default settings. It runs every Sunday at 19:00. Is it possible with this backup to restore to a backup point created one month ago, or our only choice is the last backup point?

I will be happy if you can clarify this mystery for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can restore Windows 7 at your backup point.
For more info, check [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore).

> **To use System Restore**
>
> Before you start System Restore, save any open files and close all programs. System Restore will restart your PC.
>
> Open System Restore by clicking the **Start** button [image: Picture of the Start button]. In the search box, type **System Restore**, and then, in
>   the list of results, click **System Restore**. If you're prompted for an administrator password or
>   confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
>
> Follow the steps in the wizard to choose a restore point and restore your computer.

Comment: System Restore provides me the option to restore to **System Image Restore Point** which is created by Windows Backup: http://j.mp/Ri7n4Y The dates go back to May 25, 2012 for me. I am not sure if there are really so many system images saved on my external hard drive. On the other hand, it *proves* you cannot restore the entire system if you haven't created system image.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore files to their previous versions. Each file and folder have **Previous Versions** tab on their Properties dialog:

1. Right-click file or folder, and click **Properties**.
2. Click **Previous Versions** tab.

After a while, you'll see the list of available versions. For files, it can be either **Restore Point** or **Backup**. For folders, the dialog just lists the dates when a modification occurred.

Alternatively you can go to Backup and Restore and restore files from there.

---

[JiniOnline's answer](https://superuser.com/a/516121/80304) provides info on restoring the system to a previous state.